# Issue retrieving data from Firebase Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason I can't retrieve data from Firebase. Basically the code "skips" the ref-section and moves on, and I have no clue why it does this. I have tried to look at documentation as well as other questions on StackExchange and I can't figure out the problem. please help. thanks!

```
func getMeta() {

    ref.child("Meta").child("Topics").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        if let actualValue = value {

            print(actualValue)

        }
    })
}
```

I actually want to do more things with actualValue but I can't even get the code to print it. The Firebase json looks like this:

```
{
  "Meta" : {
    "Levels" : {
      "LevelOne" : [ "q0001", "q0002" ],
      "LevelTwo" : [ "q0003" ]
    },
    "Topics" : {
      "France" : { 
           0: "q0001", 
           1: "q0002" },
      "UK" : {
           0: "q0003" }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to

```
print(snapshot)
```

after the code skips the section, I get this error

```
error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'snapshot'
snapshot ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: So to clarify "skipping the ref section" – if you add a breakpoint inside the closure there (right above `let value  = snapshot...`), it doesn't get hit?

Comment: @JohnZ : yes it does not hit. It skips to the end of the closure.

Comment: @PauloMattos yes it is not nil

Comment: If you `print(ref.url)` does it seems right?

Comment: Are you sure, that it is never printed? .observe functions are working async

Comment: @PauloMattos yes it is correct

Comment: @VladPulichev yes it skips the section - I have done other tutorials/projects with the same data base and it prints.

Answer (score 0):

**If you’re signed in using Firebase Auth,** 
**log out and try again.**

I deleted the user manually in Firebase console but in my app I was still signed in with the user. 
I logged out and the code does not skip the ref section anymore.

Hope this helps!